# Functors - how can I use them with typedef?

Tags: c++, function, functor

This is a functor:

```
class add_x {

 int x;

public:
  add_x(int x) : x(x) {}
  int operator()(int y) { return x + y; }

};
```

And from main I can do this:

```
add_x add10(10); // create my functor 
int i = add10(20); // add 20 and return it
```

How can I combine the functor with `typedef`?

For instance, I came across this:

```
typedef int (*myfuncType)(float f, char c1,char c2);
myfuncType pt2Function = NULL;
```

But what am I defining here exactly? operator `()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Function pointer is - as its name says - just a pointer to function. You cannot use a pointer to function to point to functor, which is essentially a class with overloaded () operator.

You may be interested in std::function from C++11:

```
#include <functional>

(...)
std::function<int(int)> fn = add_x(10);
int i = fn(20);
```

---

Edit: Ok, I see, what you are asking for.

Maybe some code will make things clear.

```
int fn(float a, char b, char c) { ... }

(...)

typedef int (*myFuncType)(float f, char c1, char c2);

myFuncType ptrToFun = &fn;

(*fn)(1.0f, 'a', 'z');
```

This typedef creates a "pointer-to-function" type. If you declare a variable of this type, then you'll be able to assign to it a pointer to function (extracted with regular & operator) and - for example - pass to another function or just store (or call this function).

std::function is a lot more flexible, because you can store in it a pointer to function, a functor or even a lambda and call them normally.

Comment: Ohh, now I get the question :p

Comment: I guess, that ron mixes the functor with pointer-to-function typedef. The question is very unclear, though.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it was about assigning a functor to a function pointer, which the first part answers splendidly.

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand your first question (`How can I combine the functor with typedef ?`), so I can't answer that - a `typedef` would work as it would with any other class.

Regarding your second question: the line

```
typedef int (*myfuncType)(float f, char c1,char c2);
```

gives a name (`myfunctType`) to the type `int (*)(float, char, char)` (read: "a function which takes a `float` and two `char` values and then returns an `int`").

So

```
myfuncType pt2Function = NULL;
```

Defines a variable which can point to such an above-mentioned function, but sets the pointer to NULL for now.

Answer (score 1):

Here, `myfuncType`is a type describing a pointer of function, with three float parameters and which return an int. A functor is just a class with operator() overload. So the typedef is used just like other class.

`typedef add_x add` will work.